# PartKeepr and Doctrine on Ubuntu

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

After some hours of Googling about installing PartKeepr, which requires Doctrine/ on Ubuntu, I've decided to ask this question. Can somebody give any advice of integrating Doctrine in PHP (Ubuntu)?

I've installed it with Pear and Composer, but couldn't get rid of the installation of PartKeepr: `Doctrine needs to be installed and in the PHP include_path. You can install doctrine on most Unix systems using:

> Doctrine needs to be installed and in the PHP include_path. You can install doctrine on most Unix systems using:
>
> pear channel-discover pear.symfony.com
>
> pear channel-discover pear.doctrine-project.org
>
> pear install pear.doctrine-project.org/DoctrineORM
>
> Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader was not found

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you executed the `pear` commands given by the installer? Note that you need to execute those as root, or prefix them with `sudo`.If you executed the commands, check the output for any errors.

A common issue is that `pear` installs work properly, but the `include_path` is missing from your php.ini.

You should first check which directory PEAR uses:

`pear config-show |grep "PEAR directory"`

Then check if your PHP `include_path` has the `PEAR` directory included by calling:

`php -i |grep include_path`

Note that if you are using a different `php.ini` file for your webserver, which is almost always the case, put the following PHP file into your web server root and open it in your browser to get the `include_path` for your webserver's `php.ini` configuration:

`<?php
echo ini_get("include_path");`

Make sure that `include_path` contains the path to the PEAR directory. If it doesn't, edit the `php.ini` and restart your webserver. If it does, I'm afraid you need to give more details, like operating system version and exact steps you have taken to install the `PEAR` packages.